# How to handle class variable without $this?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I'm making a WordPress plugin with OOP concept and I'm facing some wired issue.

First I have a `main-plugin.php` file where I have a class like this

```
include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'something.php';

class something {
    //some var
    public $a;
    private function __construct() { {
        //all of my wordpress hook calls are here
    }

    public function foo() {
        $this->a = 55; // this is working fine and not giving any error 
    }
}
```

Now I have another php file which holds another class which I included in the `main-plugin.php` file

let's say the new file is `something.php`

and here I have

```
class some {
    //some variables 
    public $b, $c;

    // now this this class when I'm doming 
    public function bar() {
        $this->b =1; // this is giving me error saying this is not an object.
    }   
}
```

Now I have no idea why `$this` is not working inside the else class. Also As these variables are not static variables, I really can't do `self::$b`. So, I was hoping if anyone else can tell me a way to access non static variables inside the class without using `$this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you must have instance of `AICP_ADMIN` in https://github.com/isaumya/adsense-invalid-click-protector/blob/master/adsense-invalid-click-protector.php#L91 instead of string. So try something like

```
$aicpAdmin = new AICP_ADMIN;
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $aicpAdmin, 'admin_scripts' ) );
```

Comment: May I know why are you saying that? What's the problem with passing just the class name?

Comment: If you don't pass instance, it calls method `admin_scripts` like it is static method, where you cannot use `$this`. I assumed your error was something like `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in`

Comment: Yes exactly. That's the error I'm getting. So, you are saying everytime I will call methods of other classes, instead of just passing the class name, I should first create an object of that class, and then pass the object. Or else make everything (both variables and methods) static inside my class and then call them just with the class name. I hope this is what you are trying to mean. Let me know if I'm getting you correctly or not.

Comment: Hey brother, I've tried your approach. Still getting the exact same fatal error.

Comment: Yes, create an object of that class and pass this rather than static class and methods.

Comment: I just tried it but still giving me the exact same error.

Comment: Yes it really is.This is what I did: https://github.com/isaumya/adsense-invalid-click-protector/blob/master/adsense-invalid-click-protector.php

Comment: Just try, but... Try replace `__CLASS__` with `$this` in this method https://github.com/isaumya/adsense-invalid-click-protector/blob/master/inc/admin_setup.php#L157

Comment: OK. Trying that out too.

Comment: Perfect. It's working ferfectly now. Thank you very much. You really have no idea how much you have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

`$this` is only available inside functions within the class. If you want to initialize variables, use a [construct function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
public class test
{
     public $a;
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->a = new db();
     }
}
```

When you initialize class `test` with `$test = new test()`, `$test->a` will be an instance of `db`.

Comment: Well I was using $this->b inside a function only. Sorry. I will edit the code in the question in next few min.

Comment: That's perfectly valid. My guess is your other class, whatever you're trying to assign it to is the issue. We need more info to diagnose the issue

Comment: If I give you the full GitHub project link, will that help?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: OK. Let me push a few more commit, then I'll send you the link here

Comment: Hi, Here is the repo: https://github.com/isaumya/adsense-invalid-click-protector and I'm facing issuw with `$this` in this file: https://github.com/isaumya/adsense-invalid-click-protector/blob/master/inc/admin_setup.php

Though the main plugin file is this: https://github.com/isaumya/adsense-invalid-click-protector/blob/master/adsense-invalid-click-protector.php where I'm including the above file. 

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @iSaumya Update your question with this info. Where is the exception happening, and what exactly is it?

Comment: Updated the question. Please check now.