# PHP assigning $this variable to another name

Tags: php

I am sure I've seen once example of assigning $this to another variable, single-letter to make the code typing quicker.

```
class Dclass {

    private $d = $this;
}
```

But it's not working, is throwing me an error :

> Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in ..

Comment: `$d = $this;` ?

Comment: maybe `$this->d` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle class variable without $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449782/how-to-handle-class-variable-without-this)

Comment: Posted to fast. It was actually ' private $d = $this ' in the class header, and it was not working for me. However when I place it in the constructor ' $d = $this ' is working.  So my question is why the first (with private) is not working?

Sorry for misspelling.

Comment: @linearSpin Please update the question.

Comment: _**To make code typing quicker??**_ That's a _terrible_ reason for doing something idiosyncratic for your language. You're writing code that's hard to read (which will happen many times) to save a tiny fraction of a second (one time). Use a decent editor with autocomplete and write idiomatic code.

Comment: @Chris, Not only quicker, I rather was thinking about code readability, having everywhere "$this" looks bad, and in my opinion it argues with DRY.

Comment: Replacing $this with $d (for example) is improving the code readability 10 times.

Comment: @linearSpin, for _you_ maybe. But not for other developers. `$this` is a commonly-used part of the language; `$d` is meaningless without looking for context. "This" is an English word; "d" is a letter that could represent anything. And _even if you're the only developer who ever looks at this code_ you'd be better served getting used to seeing—and using—`$this`. You'll find it in virtually every PHP codebase on the planet. Try to use each language according to its idioms. It will pay off.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so from the another post [How to handle class variable without $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449782/how-to-handle-class-variable-without-this)

```
"$this is only available inside functions within the class." @FrankerZ
```

So this kind of assignment should be done inside the class constructor, or other function?

Comment: But then you would have to use `$this->d` to use the variable, sort of defeating the easier to code request

Comment: No, instead of typing [ $this->someFunction() ] you can type [ $d->someFunction ] what is much more ergonomic in my opinion, but either way its only working in this function,  so to use it you would need to place it ( $d = $this ) in every function ..